# tinymce removes <pre> tag on load

Tags: javascript, html, tags, tinymce, pre

I am using tinyMCE and I need to share some code with my users. I store the code in database like:

```
'<pre class=\"brush: xml; fontsize: 100; first-line: 1; \">&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;</pre>'
```

And when I get it from database and put into a tinymce enabled text area the `<pre>` tags are removed and I see `<p>test</p>` in html view and test in normal view.here are mytinymce settings:

```
tinyMCE_GZ.init({
    plugins : 'save,style,layer,advhr,advimage,advlink,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,'+
    'searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,syntaxhighlighter,syntaxhl,preelementfix',
    themes : 'simple,advanced',
    languages : 'fa',
    disk_cache : true,
    debug : false
});

tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "save,safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,autosave,advlist,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,syntaxhighlighter,syntaxhl,preelementfix",
        relative_urls : false,
        remove_script_host : false,
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,restoredraft,|,insertfile,insertimage,syntaxhighlighter,syntaxhl",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "../../web/templates/filters/routes/editor.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    },

    autosave_ask_before_unload : false,
        valid_elements : '*[*]',
        extended_valid_elements : "pre[name|class]",
        save_onsavecallback:"Sol.Dss.Modify.saveContent"
});
```

Comment: This might help http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements

Comment: @yb007 As you can see in the settings I have near the end of the script I have  allowed pre tag

Comment: I have the same issue, did you solve it?